# При клике обновление данных datetimepicker?

Tags: html, jquery, веб-программирование, datetime

Есть задача - нужно, что бы при обновлении даты рождения уже существующие данные обновлялись. 
Изменения в календаре когда я изменяю месяц или год не переносятся в поле даты пока не нажмешь еще раз конкретное число

Вот сайт: https://registration.metro.ua/employee

Например, я выбрал пятое число - потом поменял месяц и год - и нажал рядом с календарем - оно не подхватит то, что я вносил. 
Можно ли как то реализовать, что бы при нажатии рядом с календарем данные обновлялись?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу, что вы применяете jquery. Обратите ваше внимание на [Datepicker jQueryMobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/datepicker/).